# Extract multiple .part splitted archives from multiple folders

Tags: batch-file

I have some splitted archives in `C:\test` this way

```
PARENT folder is C:\test
     |
     +--- subfolder1
             |         
             +-- file1.part01.rar
             +-- file1.part02.rar
             +-- file2.part01.rar
             +-- file2.part02.rar
             +.....

      +--- subfolder2
             |
             +-- file1.part1.rar
             +-- file1.part2.rar
             +-- file2.part1.rar
             +-- file2.part2.rar
             +......
```

I try to extract these folders in this way

```
PARENT folder is C:\test
     |
     +--- subfolder1
             |         
             +-- file1 [folder]
             +-- file2 [folder]
             +.....

      +--- subfolder2
             |
             +-- file1 [folder]
             +-- file2 [folder]
             +......
```

but I fails (batch seems don't start)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com') do set "CodePage=%%I"
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 65001 2>nul

set "PromptForBreak="
if /I "%~1" == "/noprompt" set "PromptForBreak=rem"

set "SourceFolder=C:\Test"
set "LogExtract=%SourceFolder%\ExtractionLog.txt"
set "LogError=%SourceFolder%\ErrorLog.txt"

del /Q "%LogExtract%" "%LogError%" 2>nul

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceFolder%\*" /AD-H /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:done') do (
    set "NoFolderMove="
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in ('dir "%SourceFolder%\%%I\*.rar" "%SourceFolder%\%%I\*.zip" /A-D-H /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
        if exist "%SourceFolder%\%%I\%%J" (
            echo Extracting "%SourceFolder%\%%I\%%J" ...
            "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -cfg- -ibck -logpfu="%LogExtract%" -o+ -y -- "%SourceFolder%\%%I\%%J" "%SourceFolder%\%%I\"
            if errorlevel 1 (
                set "NoFolderMove=1"
                set "ArchiveFile=%SourceFolder%\%%I\%%J"
                >>"%LogError%" call echo Error %%ErrorLevel%% on extracting "%%ArchiveFile%%"
            ) else (
                echo %%~nJ| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "\.part[0123456789][0123456789]*$" >nul
                if errorlevel 1 ( del /F "%SourceFolder%\%%I\%%J" ) else for %%# in ("%%~nJ") do del /F /Q "%SourceFolder%\%%I\%%~n#.part*%%~xJ"
            )
        )
    )
    if not defined NoFolderMove (
        md "%SourceFolder%\done" 2>nul
        if exist "%SourceFolder%\done\" move /Y "%SourceFolder%\%%I" "%SourceFolder%\done\" >nul
        %PromptForBreak% %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C NY /N /T 2 /D N /M "Break execution [N/Y]? "
        %PromptForBreak% if errorlevel 2 goto EndBatch
    )
)

:EndBatch
if defined CodePage %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com %CodePage%
endlocal
```

Comment: Surely to extract a multipart archive, you'd just need to isolate the `*.part01.*` or `*.part1.*` files, and, as long as all the other parts were in the same location, the extractor will find and extract those too!

Comment: Additionally, we need you to explain exactly what your issue is. You have simply told us that the batch file doesn't seem to start, how have you determined that? What happens, for instance, if you change its first line to `@echo off & %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL`. If nothing at all happens, then you have a software issue/restriction, and that is outside of the scope of this site. If you see a message with a short countdown, then your batch file clearly does work, and your problem is with part of its content. If the latter, you need to submit more debugging information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file code in the question runs without any error. It does not produce the wanted directory tree on using the four multi-volume RAR archives created by myself, but there is no error output during the batch file execution.

The following batch file can be used for this task on using *WinRAR* respectively `Rar.exe` version 5.70 or a newer version supporting the switches `-ad1` (required) and `-isnd-` (not necessary):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x -ad1 -cfg- -c- -idq -isnd- -o+ -r -y -- "C:\Test\*.rar"
if errorlevel 1 echo(& pause & exit /B
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Test\*.part*" /AD /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    if exist "%%I\%%~nI\" (
        dir "%%I" /A /B | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"%%~nI" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^." >nul
        if errorlevel 1 (
            move "%%I\%%~nI" "%%~dpI" >nul
            if not errorlevel 1 (rd "%%I") else ren "%%I" "%%~nI"
        ) else ren "%%I" "%%~nI"
    ) else ren "%%I" "%%~nI"
)
del /A-R /Q /S "C:\Test\*.rar" >nul
endlocal
```

The *RAR* command `x` and the *RAR* switches are described all in the manual of the console version of *WinRAR* which is the text file `Rar.txt` in program files directory of *WinRAR*. The manual contains at bottom also the possible exit values and their meanings.

There can be used also `UnRAR.exe` version 5.70 or newer for extracting the RAR archives which is freeware in comparison to `Rar.exe` which is shareware. `UnRAR.exe` (UnRAR for Windows) can be downloaded from [WinRAR and RAR archiver addons](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm).

The batch file executes on any error during the extraction of all archives found recursively by `Rar.exe` the command **PAUSE** to halt the batch file execution to see the error messages and then exits the batch file processing without doing the cleanup steps.

The directory `C:\Test` could have following folders and files after the extraction finished:

- **subfolder1**

  - **file1.part01**

    - **one or more extracted folders**
    - one or more extracted files
  - **file2.part1**

    - **file2**

      - **one or more extracted folders**
      - one or more extracted files
  - file1.part01.rar
  - file1.part02.rar
  - file2.part1.rar
  - file2.part2.rar
- **subfolder2**

  - **file3.part01**

    - **one or more extracted folders**
    - one or more extracted files
  - **file4.part1**

    - **file4**

      - **one or more extracted folders**
      - one or more extracted files
    - **one or more additional extracted folders**
    - one or more additional extracted files
  - file3.part01.rar
  - file3.part02.rar
  - file4.part1.rar
  - file4.part2.rar

There are not wanted the directory names ending with `.part01` or `.part1`. So the directories of which name are matched by the wildcard pattern `*.part*` are renamed by removing the "extension" `.part*`.

There could be also multi-volume RAR archives which contain just a directory with same name as the RAR archive file which contains all the archived directories and files. This is the case in the example above for `file2.part?` containing the directory `file2` with all the archived directories and files. For such archives it would be better to have finally just `file2` and not finally `file2\file2` in the directory of the multi-volume RAR archive file. For that reason `file2.part1\file2` is moved up to directory `subfolder1` with name `file2` and the now empty directory `file2.part1` is deleted by the batch code.

It is also possible that an archive contains a directory with same name as the archive file, but additionally also other directories and files as it is the case for `file4.part?`. In this case no directory move should be done because of the result would be not the same as inside the archive.

Finally the batch file deletes all RAR archive files with exception of those with read-only attribute set because of using option `/A-R`. That makes it possible to run the batch file multiple times on same directory structure on all *.rar files having the read-only attribute set and the directories created by `Rar.exe` are deleted between each execution of the batch file.

The last but one command line could be also:

```
del /A /F /Q /S "C:\Test\*.rar" >nul
```

That command line would delete really all RAR archive files in `C:\Test` and all its subdirectories.

The final result of this batch file in `C:\Test` is:

- **subfolder1**

  - **file1**

    - **one or more extracted folders**
    - one or more extracted files
  - **file2**

    - **one or more extracted folders**
    - one or more extracted files
- **subfolder2**

  - **file3**

    - **one or more extracted folders**
    - one or more extracted files
  - **file4**

    - **file4**

      - **one or more extracted folders**
      - one or more extracted files
    - **one or more additional extracted folders**
    - one or more additional extracted files

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rd /?`
- `ren /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

---

The batch file above processes **all** RAR archives and prompts the user for the password/passphrase on an archive being password protected or completely encrypted. The user has to enter the correct password/passphrase or the extraction fails for such a RAR archive which results in not doing the cleanup.

The batch file below can be used to process all **multi-volume** RAR archives in a directory tree of which first volume has a file name of which end is matched by the regular expression `part0*1\.rar` like `.part1.rar`,  `.part01.rar`, `.part001.rar`.

There is used `UnRAR.exe` which can be even of a version prior 5.70.

Other RAR archives perhaps also existing in the directory tree are not processed by this batch file.

This batch file processes also multi-volume RAR archives with a password/passphrase whereby the text file `passwords.txt` in the directory of the batch file must contain all passwords/passphrases line by line of all password protected or encrypted multi-volume RAR archives.

The batch file can be run with `/N` or `/n` as optional first argument to avoid the user prompt after finishing the extraction process.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ErrorCount="
set "ArchiveCount=0"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Test\*.part*1.rar" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /R "part0*1\.rar"') do for %%J in ("%%~nI") do (
    set /A ArchiveCount+=1
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" x -cfg- -c- -inul -pnopw -o+ -r -y -- "%%I" "%%~dpI\%%~nJ\"
    if errorlevel 11 (
        if not errorlevel 12 call :ExtractProtected "%%I" "%%~dpI\%%~nJ\"
    ) else if errorlevel 3 (
        if not errorlevel 4 call :ExtractProtected "%%I" "%%~dpI\%%~nJ\"
    )
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        del /A /F /Q "%%~dpI\%%~nJ.part*.rar"
        if exist "%%~dpI\%%~nJ\%%~nJ\" (
            dir "%%~dpI\%%~nJ" /A /B | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"%%~nJ" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^." >nul
            if errorlevel 1 (
                ren "%%~dpI\%%~nJ" "%%~nJ.tmp"
                move "%%~dpI\%%~nJ.tmp\%%~nJ" "%%~dpI\" >nul
                if not errorlevel 1 (rd "%%~dpI\%%~nJ.tmp") else ren "%%I\%%~nJ.tmp" "%%~nJ"
            )
        )
    ) else (
        if exist "%%~dpI\%%~nJ\%%~nJ\" rd "%%~dpI\%%~nJ\%%~nJ" 2>nul
        if exist "%%~dpI\%%~nJ\" rd "%%~dpI\%%~nJ" 2>nul
        echo ERROR: Failed to exctract: "%%I"
        set /A ErrorCount+=1
    )
)
goto ShowResults

:ExtractProtected
echo INFO:  Protected archive:  %1
if exist "%~dp0passwords.txt" for /F useback^ delims^=^ eol^= %%H in ("%~dp0passwords.txt") do (
    echo(%%H| "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" x -cfg- -c- -inul -p -o+ -r -y -- %1 %2
    if not errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
)
exit /B 1

:ShowResults
echo(
set "PluralS="
if not defined ErrorCount goto ShowCount
if not %ErrorCount% == 1 set "PluralS=s"
echo ERROR: Failed to extract %ErrorCount% multi-volume RAR archive%PluralS%!
set "PluralS="
:ShowCount
if not %ArchiveCount% == 1 set "PluralS=s"
echo INFO:  Extracted %ArchiveCount% multi-volume RAR archive%PluralS%!
echo(
endlocal
if /I not "%~1" == "/N" pause
```

`UnRAR.exe` is first executed for each multi-volume RAR archive with option `-pnopw` which results in an extraction of non-damaged archives with no password/passphrase or with password `nopw`.

For the password protected and the completely encrypted archives is output by `UnRAR.exe` the error message:

> Corrupt file or wrong password.

This error message is like all messages suppressed by using the switch `-inul`.

For such archives on which `UnRAR.exe` exits with value `11` (wrong password) or value `3` (invalid checksum, damaged data) the subroutine `ExtractProtected` is called to try to extract the protected archive using the passwords/passphrases stored line by line in the file `passwords.txt` in the batch file directory.

There is used the method to output the password/passphrase read from the file with command **ECHO** redirected to handle **STDIN** (standard input) of `UnRAR.exe` and using just the switch `-p` without the password/passphrase to pass correct to `UnRAR.exe` also really hard to process strings consisting of only ASCII characters like `#"!%()`. Please note that this method does nevertheless not work for all possible passwords, especially on characters with a code point value greater decimal 127 are included also in the string.

This extended batch file makes the same cleanup as the first batch file with the difference that it makes the cleanup for each successfully extracted multi-volume RAR archive. So there are only the multi-volume RAR archives remaining for which the extraction process failed, for example on required password/passphrase is not stored in the file `passwords.txt`. The batch file can be run once again on the directory tree after adding the missing password(s)/passphrase(s) to the file `passwords.txt` to process the remaining multi-volume archives if that was the reason for failed extraction and not a damaged archive or a different error.

See also DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)